# PowerShell - CSV file containing username - append with first name, last name etc

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file containing a bunch of usernames associated with computers. 
This list only contains USERNAME.

I want to append several columns with First Name, Last Name etc based on the Username. 
I'm not too familiar with PowerShell to be able to do this without any hickups.

But so far I can't even get further than this:

```
$user_list = Import-Csv C:\temp\daclientsTest.csv

$user_list.foreach(
    {
        $SAMAccountName = $_.'USERNAME'
        write-host $SAMAccountName
    }
)
```

And I get nothing from the $SAMAccountName variable. 
Anyone got any tips?

CSV file looks like this:

```
HOSTNAME;USERNAME
PC01259;10412;
PC01946;10319;
```

Obviously the list is super long and contains only these two variables. 
So I need to take the username, get certain variables and append those to new columns

Edit: If anyone wants to see the script (it's probably full of errors, but it worked so I'm happy):

```
$user_list = Import-Csv C:\temp\daclients.csv -Delimiter ';'
# Follows this format: HOSTNAME;USERNAME;

$user_list.foreach(
    {

            If ($_.USERNAME) {

                $NewObjectList = New-Object -TypeName psobject
                $Hostname = $_.HOSTNAME
                $SAMAccountName = $_.USERNAME
                $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -Properties DisplayName,extensionAttribute2,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,title
                $DisplayName = $ADUser.DisplayName
                $physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $ADUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                $title = $ADUser.title
                $EXTENSIONATTRIBUTE2 = $ADUser.extensionAttribute2


                $NewObjectList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Hostname
                $NewObjectList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value $SAMAccountName
                $NewObjectList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DisplayName -Value $DisplayName
                $NewObjectList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name title -Value $title
                $NewObjectList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ExtensionAttribute2 -Value $EXTENSIONATTRIBUTE2
                $NewObjectList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name physicalDeliveryOfficeName -Value $physicalDeliveryOfficeName

                #Create new csv-file
                $NewObjectList | export-csv -Append -Path C:\temp\daclientsNEW.csv
            }

    }
)
```

Comment: You need to use `Import-Csv C:\temp\daclientsTest.csv -Delimiter ';'` because the command uses the default culture list separator character (usually a comma) without `-Delimiter`. If `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo` is not `;`, then you need to specify it.

Comment: Aha! That worked, ok I'll try getting a bit closer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your CSV file is semicolon-delimited, you will likely need to specify that delimiter when running `Import-Csv`.

```
$user_list = Import-Csv C:\temp\daclientsTest.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

**Explanation:**

Running [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) without `-Delimiter` uses a default delimiter that matches the list separator character for your current culture. You can see your list separator character by running the following:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
```